# NullReferenceException was unhandled by usercode- Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I get NullReferenceException was unhandled by usercode in below code.

```
if (item["Area"] != null)
{
    drpArea.Items.FindByText(item["Area"].ToString()).Selected = true;//error occurs here.
}
```

Tried to figure out a million times.But i am unable to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: i think you need to test for null in drpArea.Items.FindByText(item["Area"].ToString()) as well.  Maybe even the Items property of the drpArea. I dont know the type of that variable reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you should first get `listitem` from `Dropdownlist` and than set the selected value

Try this :

```
 ListItem li = drpArea.Items.FindByText(Convert.ToString(item["Area"]));
 if (li != null)
    drpArea.SelectedValue = li.Value;
```